# GLSL: Separate sources and standalone validation

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, build-automation

I want to be able to do these things:

- Write GLSL shaders
- Separate my sources for reusability purposes
- Validate all my sources before building the main application, and exit if anything fails

The GLSL standard is written so that you can specify multiple source strings to a single shader, and it will combine them. Shaders will also pass verification with C-style prototype-and implementation structure. For example, the following pseudocode shader:

```
#version 460
out vec4 color;

vec4 getColor() {
    return vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

void main() {
    color = getColor();
}
```

Could be separated into this string:

```
#version 460
out vec4 color;

vec4 getColor();

void main() {
    color = getColor();
}
```

and this string:

```
vec4 getColor() {
    return vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

By putting each in its own file to pass to glslangvalidator, I would hope you could validate them separately.

But there's a problem, and that problem is the #version directive. If I specify #version 460 at the start of all my sources, then when OpenGL combines them, the #version will be defined twice, which is not allowed. But if I *don't*, glslangvalidator will assume version 100, and the sources will not validate properly.

I've considered a few options:

- Dynamically remove the #version directive using string manipulation function when I read the source files to embed the sources in the application. This sounds like it could work, but it also feels like a hacky workaround.
- Dynamically add the #version directive to a duplicate file and run glslangvalidator against that instead. This also sounds like it could work, but it raises doubt about the validity of the validation (it validated against a slightly different source, after all).
- Specify the GLSL version at command line. For some reason, the tool only seems to accept version 100 at command line, when I need version 460.
- #ifndef gates. The validator raises an error with this because #version has to be the very first thing in the source, without even an exception allowed for preprocessor ifs.

Is there a canonical solution to this? Perhaps something I've overlooked in the GLSL spec, or an additional flag for the validator, or even an alternate tool I can use?

Comment: What do you mean by "Separate my sources"? From what I understood you aren't talking about putting each shader in a separate file, but about splitting the content of a single shader into multiple files? Are they completely independent? Cause if they aren't wouldn't you get validation problems due to missing definitions? And how do you combine them in your app? Could you maybe add an example for a shader and how you separated it?

Comment: Ok, I've added a clarifying example. Hope this helps!